# PL/SQL- Creation of dynamic query Blocks based on a column value

Tags: join, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-programming

A column tran_type of table trans_data with values as 'V','M','MC','P'

There are multiple joins used currently as:

```
(          
    select count(tran_type) Visa, to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour from trans_data where tran_type = 'V' group by to_char(request_datetime,'hh24')
  ) b on a.src_hour = b.src_hour left join

  (
    select count(tran_type) Maestro, to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour from trans_data where switched_type = 'M' group by to_char(request_datetime,'hh24')                   
  ) c on  a.src_hour = c.src_hour left join
```

The above block would need to be repeated for additional entries like 'MC' - Mastercard and 'P' Paypal. In future, there can be many more transaction types. Is there a way, the above code could be dynamically created depending on the number of tran_type?

For ex. if tomorrow, we include 'P' PayPal, the dynamic query should look like:

```
(          
    select count(tran_type) Visa, to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour from trans_data where tran_type = 'V' group by to_char(request_datetime,'hh24')
  ) b on a.src_hour = b.src_hour left join

  (
    select count(tran_type) Maestro, to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour from trans_data where tran_type = 'M' group by to_char(request_datetime,'hh24')                   
  ) c on  a.src_hour = c.src_hour left join

(
    select count(tran_type) PayPal, to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour from trans_data where tran_type = 'P' group by to_char(request_datetime,'hh24')                   
  ) d on  a.src_hour = d.src_hour left join
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the SQL statement?  If you are just returning a weakly typed `sys_refcursor` to the caller, you can use dynamic SQL to assemble the SQL statement you execute.  If you are trying to do something with the results in PL/SQL, you'd need to use the `dbms_sql` package to execute the query and work with the results.  That adds substantially to the complexity of your code.  It would be much simpler if you returned one row per `tran_type` per `src_hour` rather than trying to dynamically add columns to a result set.

Comment: It's a part of an existing code...so changing it all together may be bit of a challenge...The new requirement is to do away with the repeating code and replace with something that can cater to future transaction types.

Comment: What are you doing with the SQL statement?

Comment: The SQL statement is to generate a daily report based on the various transactions (types). It's actually a sub-query. The other part looks like

select a.src_hour HR ,nvl(visa,0) Visa_above_sla, nvl(Maestro,0) Maestro_above_sla  from <<the code snippet in original post>>

Comment: Let's assume that we made the outer query dynamic as well.  What is the caller and what is the caller doing with the query?  If you're returning a weakly typed `sys_refcursor` to a reporting tool that is itself dynamically building the report, life is very different than if you're opening a cursor that you expect to do something with in PL/SQL.  The latter is possible, it's just more cumbersome, and the approach is going to be different.

Comment: The whole query is triggered by a java application and the results are iterated to create a report. There are no cursors used. It's a plain select query. I understand that it's not ideal, but that's how the application is coded. Is there a way to use for loops to create dynamic blocks of query?

Comment: So, you're saying that you're not using PL/SQL at all?  The Java application is constructing the SQL query that is sent to the database?  Is the Java application constructing the SQL statement dynamically?  Reading it from an XML file?  Something else?  Are you really asking how to dynamically assemble a SQL statement in Java?

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. The Java application simply uses this select query currently as a callable statement. It doesn't create it dynamically. Because, we foresee changes in future which would require manual addition of additional left joins for every new transaction type, hence the need to make it independent of new transaction types. Irrespective of the number and type of tran_types, the result should work without any code change.

Comment: Thinking of an alternative. Is there a way Stored procedure can be created which would provide counts of different transaction types over each hour and do unions to ensure we have all the types covered? i.e. say I have 2 tran types today V and M. so, it should show the 24 rows (24-hours, each of 1 hour duration) and 2 columns (count of V and count of M). Tomorrow, if there is an additional tran_type (P), we need to get the third column without any code change? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: A stored procedure could certainly have an `OUT` parameter that was a weakly typed `SYS_REFCURSOR` and could dynamically build the SQL statement.  It would generally make more sense to declare that as a function rather than a procedure, though, so that the function could return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  So long as the Java application is written to interrogate the `ResultSetMetaData` to determine the number, name, and data types of the columns that are dynamically returned.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you please provide me a brief idea on how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

For such query types you should use PIVOT clause in the select statement. The requested list of tran_type values can be dynamically changed in the "for tran_type in" list.

```
select * from
(select to_char(request_datetime,'hh24') src_hour, tran_type from trans_data)
pivot
(
   count(tran_type)
   for tran_type in ('V' as "Visa",'M' as "Maestro",'P' as "PayPal")
)
order by src_hour
```